# AngularJS record count on nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

I am angular js beginner, I have a two nested ng-repeat with custom filter, now I am trying to get the record count of Orders shown. It is working fine but after applying product filter it is not working as expected. **For example**: If order doesn't have any product to display after filtering then I don't want it to be added with my total record count shown.

My html code:

```
    <ul ng-repeat="order in Orders | filter:orderName as recordCount">
      Order Id: <b>{{order.orderName}}</b>
      <li ng-repeat="product in order.products | filter:productName as prodCount">
        <b>Name</b> : {{product.name}}, <b>Price</b>: {{product.price}}
      </li>
      <li ng-if="prodCount < 1">No Product found</li>
      <br/>
    </ul>
```

For better understanding I don't want the count of Order which shows as "*No Product found*", needed count of Order with products. 
I don't know how to proceed in order to achieve my expectation. Help needed thanks in advance.

Record count = (Number Orders shown - Number Orders with No product)

Find my fiddle "[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Karthik7724/ap5kqkcw/)".

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand very well what you want to achieve. You don't want to show this `Total records found : 3` when there are no results with the research?

Comment: No i want to show the count of order which has product

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you would like to have? I still didn't understand it very well, sorry maybe my bad :(

Comment: can you open my fiddle?

Comment: Yes I did and I have it still open

Comment: Thank you. by default it shows three Orders, I need the record count of only the order with product.

Comment: Oh, when you type something filtering by product, you don't want to see the three blocks of the order above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152169/discussion-between-karthik-n-and-quirimmo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could watch for change, then call the filter `productName` on each product to calculate the total count, something like this:

First change `ng-repeat` to store the results of the filtered list into a variable:

```
<ul ng-repeat="order in ($parent.filteredOrders = (Orders | filter:orderName))">
```

Then watch for changes, loop through the filtered list and call `productName` to check if it applies

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  $scope.totalCount = 0;

  if ($scope.filteredOrders) {
    $scope.filteredOrders.forEach(function(order) {
      var l = order.products.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if ($scope.productName(order.products[i])) {
          $scope.totalCount++;
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And then display the total:

```
{{totalCount}}
```

Edit: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57dcw3kp/)